# Eon and Eoff IGBT losses

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, igbt, switching-losses

I have read several documentations about switching losses in IGBT. Most of documents indicates to use Eon and Eoff curves to calcul the switching losses through the IGBT.

Nevertheless, the Eon and Eoff curves are obtained according to a very particular test setup which is working in CCM. Of course, my circuit does not correspond to this test setup. First observation, I m surprised to see that the Eon and Eoff are not influenced by the current capability of the IGBT driver?

About my circuit, I have several IGBTs in parallel. My circuit is working in DCM, so I have no problem of reverse recovery diode. Nevertheless the current collector is high at the instant of the turn on (Forward topology with "output buck converter" working in CCM).

I conclude that the Eon and Eoff curve won't help me for finding the switching losses. The best idea that I have is to simulate my converter through LTspice and extract the losses. I will try to include parasitic component into my simulation. Is there someone with a better idea? Is there someone who knows how to mathematically model the switching transition of an IGBT with tail current? If it was a MOSFET it would be a bit simpler to me but it will still be hard.

Comment: Use a simulator is my advice for what it's worth. Model A CCM circuit to check that sim results match the losses calculated via Eon and Eoff curves then you can be fairly sure that a DCM model will be fairly accurate.

Comment: Thank you for this advice !

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392164/is-this-the-correct-way-to-calculate-igbt-power-loss

Comment: Thank you JonRB but his calcul depends on the circuit. Those calculs are correct if your circuit looks like the one given in the datasheet. That's not my case.